# Allow blank value in React controlled input without updating state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a shopping cart with controlled input fields to manage quantity:

```
 // quantity is obtained from my redux state and the onChange dispatches such changes
 <input type='text' value={quantity} onChange={onQuantityChange} />
```

I would like the user to be able to backspace over the current quantity and retype a new one. However this effectively sets my quantity to undefined/0 and removes the product from the cart immediately. Is there a way that I can let the value be erased and the state not updated till another value is provided? Or muse I use uncontrolled inputs for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the state of your component to hold the current value of the Textfield and only dispatch when it has a new value. On componentDidMount set the value from redux onto the state.